# Ext.js problems building model relations from json

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, model, extjs4

In my project, I need to create a questionnaire (a form). The questions are generated dynamically depending on a category, and are on a server, in a database.
To get the questions a REST API is used, so sending a request to /getquestions/1 returns a JSON having all the data needed for form generation.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "questions":[  
        {  
           "id":4,
           "text":"Question1",
           "type":"NUMBER",
           "mandatory":true,
           "visible":true
        },
        {  
           "id":5,
           "text":"Dropdown type question",
           "type":"DROPDOWN",
           "mandatory":true,
           "visible":true,
           "values":[  
              {  
                 "id":1,
                 "text":"Answer1",
                 "selected":false
              },
              {  
                 "id":2,
                 "text":"Answer2",
                 "selected":false
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "id":7,
           "text":"Question 3 as Radio",
           "type":"RADIO",
           "mandatory":false,
           "visible":false,
           "values":[  
              {  
                 "id":1,
                 "text":"Yes",
                 "selected":false
              },
              {  
                 "id":2,
                 "text":"No",
                 "selected":false
              }
           ],
           "dependencies":{  
              "mark_visible":[  
                 {  
                    "question_id":5,
                    "operation":"=",
                    "value":2
                 }
              ],
              "mark_mandatory":[  
                 {  
                    "question_id":5,
                    "operation":"=",
                    "value":2
                 },
                 {  
                    "question_id":4,
                    "operation":"<=",
                    "value":5000
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
  }
```

]
}

I have store and model for questions. 
I think I need a store for values as well, to make it visible in a dropdown list, and another one for the dependencies too.

I just wondering, whether is it possible to fill all stores somehow without any explicite coding, using ext and model relations like hasMany and so.

I am basically looking for the best practice and fastest solution in Ext.js to create models and relations out of this JSON

any idea woud be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate a model and its associations from JSON data you need to have it go through a reader class (e.g. `Ext.data.JsonReader`) where it will move down the 'tree' creating the associations.

If you are loading through a proxy this should happen automatically (as it uses a reader by default). If your JSON is coming from an AJAX call and you are creating the model instance with an `Ext.create` call then you need to do the reader bit yourself. Something like:

```
var data = [...];

var reader = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonReader', {
        model: 'MyModel'
});

var resultset = reader.readRecords(data);

console.log(resultset.getRecords()[0]); // logs first read record
```